# preg_match_all doesn't match properly when caret is used?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Actually i am trying to practice regex modifiers, specially the multi-line one `m`, so wrote this simple test string:

```
$subject = "ABC
Some text DEF.
GHI
Some text JKL and some text MNO.
PQR
";
```

To match only capital litters at line start, so i wrote:

```
preg_match_all('/^[A-Z][A-Z]+/m',$subject,$m);
```

but only got:

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
  array(1) {
   [0]=> string(3) "ABC"
  }
}
```

I also tried `misU` modifiers, with no expected result also:

```
preg_match_all('/^[A-Z][A-Z]+/misU',$subject,$m);
```

but when i test on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2ONLNb/1) i got the expected result

[image]
but also strangely when i copied the code generated from the regex101 itself, it didn't work also.

> Code from Regex101

```
$re = '/^[A-Z][A-Z]+/m';
$str = 'ABC
Some text DEF.
GHI
Some text JKL and some text MNO.
PQR
    ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason it's not matching is due to leading spaces ending up in the code after you copy/paste from the regex editor; remove the leading spaces from the string or adjust the pattern.

```
$re = '/^\s*[A-Z][A-Z]+/m';
// this will accommodate leading spaces
```

**Otherwise fix the code** (remove the leading spaces):

```
<?php

$re = '/^[A-Z][A-Z]+/m';
$str = 'ABC
Some text DEF.
GHI
Some text JKL and some text MNO.
PQR
    ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);

?>
```

**Result**:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "ABC"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "GHI"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "PQR"
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, i thought when i hit enter it will not count automatic tabs. my mistake. thank you